# UbiquityIdentityToken returns nil although signed in to iCloud

Tags: macos, icloud, nsfilemanager

I have a Mac app that uses iCloud. One user complains that iCloud is not working for him, although he is signed in and sharing for "Documents & Data" is checked (I confirmed this).

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken] is returning nil and I don't understand why.

It's a production app distributed through the Mac App Store. Hundreds of other people use it with iCloud and it works just fine.

Is there anything that I cloud have this user check on his system (other than that he is signed in and turns on sharing for Documents and Data)?

Comment: same problem here... did you end up with a solution?

Comment: @MatterGoal no solution yet...

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I got the same problem here...